# Raylib Makefile Issue

Tags: makefile, mingw, raylib

I've install raylib according to [this](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-on-Windows) wiki page.

My Project Folder is look like this:
[this][1]

````
> ..\build>mingw32-make

g++ ../main.cpp -o test.exe -O2 -Wall -Wno-missing-braces -I ../include/ -L ../lib/ -lraylib -lopeng132 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
D:/Software/raylib/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopeng132
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:2: default] Error 1```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK2X3.png
````

Comment: It looks to me like you typed *openg132* (note one-three-two) where you meant to type *opengl32* (note ell-three-two) somewhere in your makefile, but you haven't shown us the makefile content that generates this link line so we can't be sure.

Comment: default:
 g++ ../main.cpp -o test.exe -O2 -Wall -Wno-missing-braces -I ../include/ -L ../lib/ -lraylib -lopeng132 -lgdi32 -lwinmm

Comment: so i just changed the lopeng132 to opengl32 and my problem is solved thanks @MadScientist

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have typed `openg132` instead of `opengl132`. You have mistaken the letter `l` for the number `1`